# In my kerneldriver is "reinterpret_cast" undefined

Tags: c

I need to use reinterpret_cast in my kernel driver which is written in C. But it says that reinterpret_cast is undefined.

I hope someone knows the solution to this problem.

Comment: C doesn't have `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: It is important that one learn the difference between C and C++ before attempting to write kernel drivers. Working properly in the kernel requires attention to fine detail, including details of language semantics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reinterpret_cast` is a C++ operator. It does not exist in C. And you do not need to use it; whatever you are attempting can be done some other way in C.